# Why is my scanner not reading from my file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get my program to read data from a text file and store it in an array. The text file contains data about a planet.
Here is an example:

```
Mercury
4.151002e10
2.642029e10
-1.714167e9
-3.518882e4
4.355473e4
6.785804e3
3.302e23
```

My file is named test.txt. It lives in the same directory as my class.java file. I've used `System.out.println(new File("test.txt").getAbsolutePath());` to check if the directory path is correct, which it was, and I used `System.out.println(new File("."));` to check if it was in the same directory that the code was trying to compile in, which again it was (outputted just a dot which I was led to believe meant it was in the correct directory). I've tried different ways of finding the file, such as renaming it to something else to check it wasn't a keyword, changing the encoding of the file to Unicode, or UTF-8, or ANSI, none of which worked, using `.\test` in the file to look in the same directory, none of which worked.

Here is my code:

```
public static void defaultPlanetArray(){
  Planet[] solarSystem;
  solarSystem = new Planet[9];
  PhysicsVector dummyAcceleration = new PhysicsVector();

  System.out.println(new File("test.txt").getAbsolutePath());
  System.out.println(new File("."));

  try{
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Lizi\\Documents\\Uni Work\\Year 2\\PHYS281\\Project\\test.txt");
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file);
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found!");
  }
  int i = 0;

  while(i<9 && scnr.hasNextLine()){
    //read values from file and set as Planet object, then set to array.
    i++
  }
```

PhysicsVector and Planet are both classes I have created. PhysicsVector and the rest of Planet apart from this excerpt compile with no problems. When I try to compile this specific bit of code, I get:

`.\Planet.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
      while(i<9 && scnr.hasNextLine()){
                   ^`

I'm guessing this means that the variable scnr is not being created in the try section because it cannot find the file. I think this because when I don't include the try and catch blocks, I get:

`.\Planet.java:59: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file);
                       ^`

I've also tried the `catches FileNotFoundException` when I'm first creating the method but that gives me the same error as immediately above.

I could just set the values in the program, but that would give a lot of unnecessary code and be rather inefficient I think.

So my question is, how do I get the scanner to read my values from the file?

Comment: Scanner is in local scope define it outside try block.

Comment: @LalitVerma If I don't put the scanner inside the try block, I get an unreported exception error. Was that what you meant?

Comment: am saying for symbol not found scnr, you accessing it outside its scope

Comment: @LalitVerma Ah I understand now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lalit Verma pointed the `scnr` variable you defined lives inside the try - catch block.

Change the code to:

```
try{
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Lizi\\Documents\\Uni Work\\Year 2\\PHYS281\\Project\\test.txt");
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file);
    int i = 0;

    while(i<9 && scnr.hasNextLine()){
      //read values from file and set as Planet object, then set to array.
      i++
    }
  }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found!");
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it! I feel a bit stupid that it was such a small error, thank you!

Comment: @LalitVerma I did on your comment, forgot to tag you though, fixed it now :)